# Tools for testing connection speed to router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm setting up a new home network, and I want to test the various connection speeds I'm getting, from different setups. Specifically, I want to know how the connection from a device to the router varies when I use WiFi, Ethernet and Powerline.

Obviously, which of those I use won't change the connection between the router and the internet ... but I want to know what connection speeds I'm getting between the device and the router.
My internet connection isn't very stable, so I don't want to just test the internet speed from the devices since that won't be a stable baseline. Also it won't tell me whether the device-router connection is close to being a limitting factor or not.

I'm an experienced full-stack software developer, but not a network specialist.
**What are the best tools / methods for me to do this?**

My *ideal* tool would look a lot like the Ookla SpeedTest app, but would show me a network map and ask me which other device on the network I wanted to test the connection to. #optimism

The devices I have available to perform this testing are:

- 2 x Windows 10 Laptops.
- 1 x Windows 10 Desktop.
- 4 x iOS phones/tablets.

I don't know a huge amount about my router; it's a ZYXEL VMG8324-B10A, running its default software. I can connect to it over `telnet` but I don't actually know anything about `telnet` other than "it's a thing that you can use to talk to your router on a console".

Comment: I have a couple answers in my profile for using iperf/jperf to do exactly this. Not sure why this was closed actually. Use two computers on your lan to test the lan side of the router, ask a friend to install iperf, set it to server and port forward for you. The wan side isn't going to be exact because you dont have control of the packets to their end destination. It should be close enough for your purpose. I'm sure you can also find tutorials on Google to set it up ~regards

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1334370/how-to-compare-two-network-adapters/1334763#1334763