# Websites sometimes load and sometimes not (tried everything available on the internet)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns

I have freshly installed Windows 10 Pro (Version 1909, OS build 18363.836) on my laptop. I've connected to my home wi-fi which works well without any problems on other devices and on the same machine with other Linux operating systems. Only on Windows, websites sometimes load, sometimes do not even when there is no problem with the internet connectivity. Bing is the only website which always loads correctly. I see this problem on many browsers including Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Brave. Although, downloads of Windows updates or Steam games happen pretty fast.

I've done what is mentioned [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1211083/ping-works-fine-but-no-internet-connection-in-browser?rq=1), changed DNS to 8.8.8.8/8.8.8.4, disabled IPv6, disabled firewall, reset my wi-fi driver (RTL8723DE wi-fi card), reset my router, even installed the whole Windows for the same, but I'm still getting the same problem. I cannot understand why. Sometimes, websites load after reloading 2-3 times. But loading happens erratically. I've set MTU to 1454, there is no packet loss when I ping www.google.com. On the same wi-fi network, I connected my laptop to the mobile phone by USB cable and the there isn't any problem regarding website loading when internet is accessed using USB tethering. There is no problem when I connect the laptop to another wi-fi network (wirelessly). The problem lies only with one particular wi-fi network.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you updated the drivers from the manufacturer? & Have you tried running iperf on the local network, I'm interested to see if it's showing large packet loss or interruptions on the LAN side of things. Who is the ISP, and what type of connection is it?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I've updated the drivers. Connection type is PPoE. I've downloaded iperf but have a hard time figuring out how to use it. My MTU is set to 1454 (there is no packet loss when I ping google).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart On the same wi-fi network, when I connect my laptop to the mobile phone by USB cable, there isn't any problem regarding website loading (when internet is accessed using USB tethering). There is no problem when I connect the laptop to another wi-fi network (wirelessly). The problem lies only with one particular wi-fi network.

Comment: Did you allow windows to update them, or did you actually go to the manufacturer website to download them? I would recommend the latter. This answer explains how to use jperf, the GUI version of iperf. https://superuser.com/questions/1334370/how-to-compare-two-network-adapters/1334763#1334763